# Access/ Excel integration:How to avoid conflicts between simultaneous users?

Tags: sql, excel, database, vba, ms-access

I'm developing an excel tool which connects to an Access database through VBA, and data is transferred between excel and the DB upon user requests. Each user have his own version of the excel workbook, which connects to the central db. In most cases this works fine, but i have discovered some conflicts when two users are trying to connect at the same time, causing one of the users excel/VBA to crash without any VBA errorcode.

I suspect this is caused by the database the connection somehow being interrupted by the second user.

So my question is: 
Is there a way to "lock" the connection when the first user has connected and then knowing the db is in use when the second user tries to connect, so his request can be aborted/delayed, without excel crashing?

I have included the code for one of the transactions, which moves data from excel to the database.

```vb
Public Sub ExportToAccess()

''''Establish connection to DB
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
cn.Open


Set rstDbTable = New ADODB.Recordset

With rstDbTable

    .Open "AllCapacity", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable

End With

''''Move data''''
'one area at the time

For area = 0 To UBound(cap_areas)

    toDbArray = sh_capacity.Range(cap_areas(area)) 'Save the range in question ot the db array. starts at 1

    'MsgBox (toDbArray(1, 1))

    For i = 1 To UBound(toDbArray, 1) 'for all rows

            rstDbTable.Filter = "CapArea = '" & NamesArea(area) & "'" _
            & " AND Week = '" & week & "'" _
            & " AND AreaWeekID = '" & i & "'"

        If rstDbTable.EOF Then 'Check if its empty and then create new records
            MsgBox ("Could not find row in DB. Script is ending. CapArea =" & NamesArea(area) & ". AreaWeekId = " & i)
            Stop ' Debugger
            GoTo EndOfCode

            'rstDbTable.AddNew 'Use if we need to add new row

        Else
                'rstDbTable("AreaWeekID").Value = toDbArray(i, 27)
                'rstDbTable("Week").Value = toDbArray(i, 28)
                'rstDbTable("CapArea").Value = toDbArray(i, 29)
                'start = Timer

                rstDbTable("MO_DA").Value = toDbArray(i, 2)
               ' MsgBox (Timer - start)

                rstDbTable("MO_EV").Value = toDbArray(i, 3)
                rstDbTable("MO_NI").Value = toDbArray(i, 4)
                rstDbTable("TU_DA").Value = toDbArray(i, 5)
                rstDbTable("TU_EV").Value = toDbArray(i, 6)
                rstDbTable("TU_NI").Value = toDbArray(i, 7)
                rstDbTable("WE_DA").Value = toDbArray(i, 8)
                rstDbTable("WE_EV").Value = toDbArray(i, 9)
                rstDbTable("WE_NI").Value = toDbArray(i, 10)
                rstDbTable("TH_DA").Value = toDbArray(i, 11)
                rstDbTable("TH_EV").Value = toDbArray(i, 12)
                rstDbTable("TH_NI").Value = toDbArray(i, 13)
                rstDbTable("FR_DA").Value = toDbArray(i, 14)
                rstDbTable("FR_EV").Value = toDbArray(i, 15)
                rstDbTable("FR_NI").Value = toDbArray(i, 16)
                rstDbTable("SA_DA").Value = toDbArray(i, 17)
                rstDbTable("SA_EV").Value = toDbArray(i, 18)
                rstDbTable("SA_NI").Value = toDbArray(i, 19)
                rstDbTable("SU_DA").Value = toDbArray(i, 20)
                rstDbTable("SU_EV").Value = toDbArray(i, 21)
                rstDbTable("SU_NI").Value = toDbArray(i, 22)



        End If

        rstDbTable.Update

    Next i
Next area

EndOfCode:
rstDbTable.Close
```

Comment: Did you try to use `adLockOptimistic` locking type? And I would select `adOpenDynamic` recordset type

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I've tried both of your suggestions, but the problem remains.